# karma/jasmine angular tests fails on osx

Tags: angularjs, macos, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a big angular app whose tests have been running fine through grunt-karma/karma-jasmine since the beginning of the project. Recently, tests began to fail most of the time and I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I have a git commit that works every times, and the next one fails most of the times, and the next ones two. I've been fiddling with it for hours without being able to isolate anything that would make the tests pass on a consistent basis. Every time I think I have found what was tripping up the test suite, trying to use that knowledge a few commits later ends up in error anyway.

The first 25 tests always pass ok, and then I get an error message that doesn't bring much to the table :

        `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app-module-common due to:
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=
            at /Users/hudson/workspace/app-recast-master/build/js/bottom/vendor/dev/20-angular.js:3802`

The weird thing in this message is that no provider is specified as being unknown.

This is happening on the osx based box that is in charge of building the site, but not on my windows machine.

Here is what the karma.conf looks like:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var exportedConf = require('./build.js');
  var userConfig = exportedConf.userConfig;

  module.exports = function (config) {

    config.set({
      // Karma configuration

      // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
      basePath: '',

      // frameworks to use
      frameworks: ["jasmine"],

      // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
      files: [
        '../' + userConfig.build_dir + '/js/top/vendor/dev/**/*.js',
        //'../' + userConfig.build_dir + '/js/top/project-root/**/*.js',
        '../' + userConfig.src_dir + '/fragments/config.js',
        '../' + userConfig.build_dir + '/js/bottom/vendor/dev/**/*.js',
        '../' + userConfig.build_dir + '/js/bottom/project-root/**/*.js',
        '../test/mockFactory.js',
        '../test/jasmineVersionCheck.js',
        '../' + userConfig.project_dir + '/**/' + userConfig.tests_folderName + '/**/*.spec.js'
      ],

      // list of files to exclude
      exclude: [
      ],

      preprocessors: {
        // preprocessors are defined at the end of file so that we can use the userConfig variables in the key
      },

      // test results reporter to use
      reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],

      coverageReporter: {
        dir: '../' + userConfig.reports_dir + '/',
        reporters: [
          {
            type: 'cobertura',
            file: 'coverage.xml'
          },
          {
            type: 'html',
            file: 'coverage.html'
          }
        ]
      },


      // web server port
      port: process.env.KARMA_PORT || 8080,

      // cli runner port
      runnerPort: process.env.KARMA_RUNNER_PORT || 9100,


      junitReporter: {
        outputFile: '../' + userConfig.reports_dir + '/test-results.xml'
      },



      // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
      colors: process.env.KARMA_COLORS || true,

      // level of logging
      // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

      // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
      autoWatch: false,

      // Start these browsers, currently available:
      // - Chrome
      // - ChromeCanary
      // - Firefox
      // - Opera
      // - Safari (only Mac)
      // - PhantomJS
      // - IE (only Windows)
      browsers: [process.env.KARMA_BROWSER || 'PhantomJS'],

      // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
      captureTimeout: 5000,

      // Continuous Integration mode
      // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
      singleRun: true,

      plugins: ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher', 'karma-junit-reporter', 'karma-coverage']


    });

    // polyfills need to be excluded or instanbul instrumentation goes wild and screws it all!
    config.preprocessors['../' + userConfig.build_dir + '/js/bottom/project-root/**/!(*-polyfills)+(.js)'] = ['coverage'];
  };
}());
```

I hope someone can give me a hint on the matter, I have exhausted all the options I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, i really say, maybe, it might be due to the camel cased file names. IOs doesn't consider the case when it comes to file names.

I will edit my answer if i can come to any better idea.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't sounds very likely all things considered :/